# SelectField forces me to select a choice from drop down

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I'm creating a flask form which has the email, address, state, postal code and country. Only the email is a mandatory field. None of the others are. However, Flask WTForms is forcing the user to select a state and a country from the drop down.

State and Country are both drop down options.

```
class UserForm(FlaskForm):
    email = EmailField('E-Mail', validators=[InputRequired()])
    address1 = StringField('Address line 1', render_kw={"placeholder": "Address line 1"})
    address2 = StringField('Address line 2', render_kw={"placeholder": "Address line 2"})
    city = StringField('City', render_kw={"placeholder": "City"})
    state = SelectField('State', [validators.Optional()], default=None, choices=statesList(), render_kw={"placeholder": "State"})
    postal_code = StringField('Postal Code', render_kw={"placeholder": "Postal Code"})
    country = SelectField('Country', default=None, choices=countriesList(), coerce=str, render_kw={"placeholder": "Country"})

@app.route('/create_user', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def createUser():
    form=UserForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        return render_template('confirm_user.html', email=form.email.data,
address1=form.address1.data,
address2=form.address2.data,
city=form.city.data,
state=form.state.data,
postal_code=form.postal_code.data,
country=form.country.data)
```

I even made the state an optional field. This only happens to drop-down fields.

I looked at a couple of posts on StackOverflow already but they do not answer this. Those posts suggest that the choices be removed. I need the state and country drop downs to be visible but the user does not need to make a selection if they don't want to. In this case, I'll just return a blank value to the database.

Can someone tell me how I can achieve this please?

Comment: A select field by definition requires something to be chosen, so add an option that represents the non-choice in the UI.  e.g.  `[('Choose a State', 'XX'), ('Arizona', 'AZ') `  Then default to the Pick an Option choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply provide an option to represent the non-choice.  E.g.

```
def states_list():
   return [('XX', 'Pick a Choice'), ('AZ', 'Arizona')]

class UserForm(FlaskForm):
    state = SelectField('State', choices=states_list(), default='XX')

@app.route('/create_user', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def createUser():
    form=UserForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        if form.state.data == 'XX':
            return 'No State Chosen'
        return '{} Chosen'.format(form.state.data)
    return render_template('form.html', form=form)
```